# Bootstrap 4 order sm (mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a section on my site container-fluid,row, with two equal col-md-4 sections. the right section has image, the left has header and paragraph on the next row it switches image on the left and header/paragraph on right and so on for six sections. I am trying to re order for mobile where the image is above the header / P on every section. I have tried using order-sm-1 and order-sm-2 on the divs but not having luck. it is just changing the order on all breakpoints. here is first section.....

```
<div class="container-fluid pt-5 pb-5 process">
    <div class="row text-left p-5 mb-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
            <h3>Implementation</h3>
        <p class="text-secondary">We've refined implementation to an industry-leading procedure, from 'taxi' to 'lift-off'. 
            We're with you every step of the way, holding your hand as much or as little as you see fit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mr-5 text-center"><img src="images/onboard.svg" width="400" class="img-fluid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you do some screencast video or photo about the layout you want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: As you can see in mobile the top section image goes under the text....I'd like them all to look like the next "Company Size" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a `order-sm-*` class similar to how `col-sm-*` has been changed to `col-*` so I believe the answer would be to do:

```
<div class="container-fluid pt-5 pb-5 process">
    <div class="row text-left p-5 mb-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="order-2 order-md-1 col-md-4">
            <div class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
            <h3>Implementation</h3>
        <p class="text-secondary">We've refined implementation to an industry-leading procedure, from 'taxi' to 'lift-off'. 
        We're with you every step of the way, holding your hand as much or as little as you see fit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-1 order-md-2 col-md-4 mr-5 text-center"><img src="images/onboard.svg" width="400" class="img-fluid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you! I forgot about the removal of col-sm-* in B4..DOE!

Comment: you can use `order-sm-*` and `col-sm-*`, you were probably using it incorrectly. `col-xs-*` has changed to `col-*` not `col-sm-*`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid pt-5 pb-5 process">
    <div class="row text-left p-5 mb-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-4 order-2 order-md-0">
            <div class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
            <h3>Implementation</h3>
        <p class="text-secondary">We've refined implementation to an industry-leading procedure, from 'taxi' to 'lift-off'. 
            We're with you every step of the way, holding your hand as much or as little as you see fit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mr-5 text-center order-1 order-md-0"><img src="images/onboard.svg" width="400" class="img-fluid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anything smaller than medium (xs & sm) will have image at top as its order is set to 1 and the other div has order 2. In med+ the orders are 0, they are small value so will be order normally.